# How to overrule .hide() with click to re-show all items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display all items in a content switcher(box1, box2, etc) that displays once you click their targeted button.

I've included a remove button with a .show(); targeting the specific class, but it seems that .hide() outside of the click function is overruling the .show().

What I'm trying to do?

*(Once the red x div is clicked, then all items (.r-target) should display)*

```js
$('.r-picker li').click(function() {
  /* adds remove button  */
  $('.r-picker .r-picker-remover').hide();
  $('.data', this).append('<div class="r-picker-remover">x</div>');

  $('.r-picker-remover').click(function() {
    $('.r-target').show();
  });

  /* box content switcher */
  $('.r-target').hide(); /* If button gets clicked, all list gets hidden */
  $('.r-list' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.r-picker {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.r-picker li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.r-picker li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.r-picker-remover {
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r-picker">
  <ul>
    <li target="1">
      <div class="data">
        box 1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li target="2">
      <div class="data">
        box 2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li target="3">
      <div class="data">
        box 3
      </div>
    </li>
    <li target="4">
      <div class="data">
        box 4
      </div>
    </li>
    <li target="5">
      <div class="data">
        box 5
      </div>
    </li>
    <li target="6">
      <div class="data">
        box 6
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="r-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="r-target r-list1">content box 1</li>
    <li class="r-target r-list2">content box 2</li>
    <li class="r-target r-list3">content box 3</li>
    <li class="r-target r-list4">content box 4</li>
    <li class="r-target r-list5">content box 5</li>
    <li class="r-target r-list6">content box 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now, clearly `$('.r-target').hide();` is overriding the following code:

```
$('.r-picker-remover').click(function()
{
   $('.r-target').show();
});
```

What I can't figure out is how to make that click function work because every time I click on an `.r-picker li` to switch the content in the box, it ads display: none; to all of the `.r-target`.

**How can I overcome this issue?**

I tried using `$('.r-picker li').one('click', function({ //code here });` instead of `$('.r-picker li').click(function() { //code here });` but sadly that won't work because it blocks the content switcher from firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you click on `.r-picker-remover`, the click bubbles out to the `li`. So it shows all the boxes, and then hides them again.

Use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop it from bubbling.

Also, instead of adding the click handler every time you add the remover, use event delegation to bind the handler once. Your way was adding multiple event handlers to every remover every time you clicked on the `li`.

```js
$('.data').on("click", ".r-picker-remover", function(e) {
  $('.r-target').show();
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.r-picker li').click(function() {
  /* adds remove button  */
  $('.r-picker .r-picker-remover').hide();
  $('.data', this).append('<div class="r-picker-remover">x</div>');


  /* box content switcher */
  $('.r-target').hide(); /* If button gets clicked, all list gets hidden */
  $('.r-list' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.r-picker {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.r-picker li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.r-picker li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.r-picker-remover {
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r-picker">
  <ul>
    <li target="1">
      <div class="data">
        box 1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li target="2">
      <div class="data">
        box 2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li target="3">
      <div class="data">
        box 3
      </div>
    </li>
    <li target="4">
      <div class="data">
        box 4
      </div>
    </li>
    <li target="5">
      <div class="data">
        box 5
      </div>
    </li>
    <li target="6">
      <div class="data">
        box 6
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="r-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="r-target r-list1">content box 1</li>
    <li class="r-target r-list2">content box 2</li>
    <li class="r-target r-list3">content box 3</li>
    <li class="r-target r-list4">content box 4</li>
    <li class="r-target r-list5">content box 5</li>
    <li class="r-target r-list6">content box 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I went to read about event delegations and event bubbling, and it makes complete sense now. Thanks for the detailed explanation @Barmar, exactly what I needed to understand where I went wrong.